# Importing ArrayList from one file to another

Tags: java, arraylist

my question is pretty basic, but I can't seem to find any real help in the questions other people asked...their code is way too complicated.

Basically, I created an ArrayList in one java file, and I'm trying to import it to another java file.  Can I do this?  Or do I just need to rebuild it my 2nd file?

Thanks in advance!

This is the file that created ohnode:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class trimgroup {


public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, StringIndexOutOfBoundsException, NumberFormatException{
Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("VspAircraft_calculix_geom.dat"));
Scanner scan1 = new Scanner(new File("VspAircraft_calculix_geom.dat"));  
Scanner scan2 = new Scanner(new File("VspAircraft_calculix_geom.dat"));
FileWriter file = new FileWriter(new File("trimgroup.dat"));



double ymax=0;
double ymin1=0;
double ymin=0;
double ymineq=0;
double xmax=0;
double xmin1=0;
double xmin=0;
double xmineq=0;
double ymaxb=0;
double ymin1b=0;
double yminb=0;
double ymineqb=0;
double xmaxb=0;
double xmin1b=0;
double xminb=0;
double xmineqb=0;


ArrayList<Double> a = new ArrayList<Double>(); //y values of all the nodes
ArrayList<Double> b = new ArrayList<Double>(); //x values of all the nodes
ArrayList<Integer> node = new ArrayList<Integer>(); //all the nodes on the wing
ArrayList<Integer> nodeb = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ArrayList<Integer> ohnode = new ArrayList<Integer>();



//Front Spar
while(scan.hasNextLine()){
 String line = scan.nextLine();
 String [] token = line.split("[,|\\r?\\n]");

 if (token.length==2){

     for(int i=0;i<token[1].length()-11;i++) {

        if (token[1].substring(i,i+12).equals(" NSET=Nspar1")){
        line=scan.nextLine();      // first skip any input that matches the delimiter pattern, and then attempt to return the next token

            while(scan.hasNextLine()){

            String [] token2= line.split("[,|\\r?\\n]");

                if (token2[0].equals("")){
                    break;
                }else{
                    String [] token3= line.split("[,|\\r?\\n]");
                    double token2d=Double.parseDouble(token3[2]);
                    double token1d=Double.parseDouble(token3[1]);
                    int token0d=Integer.parseInt(token3[0]);
                    a.add(token2d);
                    node.add(token0d);
                    //Find the max/min
                        if (token2d>ymax){
                            ymax=Double.parseDouble(token3[2]);

                        }else{
                        ymin1=Double.parseDouble(token3[2]);}

                        if (1/ymin1>ymineq){
                            ymin=token2d;
                            ymineq=1/token2d;}

                        if (token1d>xmax){
                            xmax=Double.parseDouble(token3[1]);

                        }else{
                            xmin1=Double.parseDouble(token3[1]);}

                        if (1/xmin1>xmineq){
                            xmin=token1d;
                            xmineq=1/token1d;}

                            line=scan.nextLine();               
                }
            } 
        }    
    }
  }
}
//Back Spar
while(scan1.hasNextLine()){
 String line = scan1.nextLine();
 String [] token = line.split("[,|\\r?\\n]");
  if (token.length==2){

     for(int i=0;i<token[1].length()-11;i++) {

        if (token[1].substring(i,i+12).equals(" NSET=Nspar2")){
        line=scan1.nextLine();       

            while(scan1.hasNextLine()){

            String [] token2= line.split("[,|\\r?\\n]");

                if (token2[0].equals("")){
                    break;
                }else{
                    String [] token3= line.split("[,|\\r?\\n]");
                    double token2d=Double.parseDouble(token3[2]);
                    double token1d=Double.parseDouble(token3[1]);
                    int token0d=Integer.parseInt(token3[0]);
                    a.add(token2d);
                    node.add(token0d);
                        if (token2d>ymaxb){
                            ymaxb=Double.parseDouble(token3[2]);

                        }else{
                        ymin1b=Double.parseDouble(token3[2]);}

                        if (1/ymin1b>ymineqb){
                            yminb=token2d;
                            ymineqb=1/token2d;}

                        if (token1d>xmaxb){
                            xmaxb=Double.parseDouble(token3[1]);

                        }else{
                            xmin1b=Double.parseDouble(token3[1]);}

                        if (1/xmin1b>xmineqb){
                            xminb=token1d;
                            xmineqb=1/token1d;}

                            line=scan1.nextLine();               
                }
            } 
        }    
    }
  }
}

while(scan2.hasNextLine()){
 String line2 = scan2.nextLine();
 String [] token2 = line2.split("[,|\\r?\\n]");

 if (token2.length==2){

  if (token2[1].equals(" NSET=Nupperskin")){
    line2=scan2.nextLine();
    while (scan2.hasNextLine()){
    String [] token2b = line2.split("[,|\\r?\\n]");
    if (token2b[0].equals("")){
     break;
    }else{
        String [] token3b = line2.split("[,|\\r?\\n]");
        int token2bi=Integer.parseInt(token3b[0]);
        double token2by=Double.parseDouble(token3b[2]);
        double token2bx=Double.parseDouble(token3b[1]);
        if (token2bx<(xmax-xmin)/(ymax-ymin)*token2by+xmin){
            ohnode.add(token2bi);
        }
        if (token2bx>(xmaxb-xminb)/(ymaxb-yminb)*token2by+xminb){
            ohnode.add(token2bi);
        }

     line2=scan2.nextLine();
     }
    }
   }
 }
 if (token2.length==2){

  if (token2[1].equals(" NSET=Nlowerskin")){
    line2=scan2.nextLine();
    while (scan2.hasNextLine()){
    String [] token2b = line2.split("[,|\\r?\\n]");
    if (token2b[0].equals("")){
     break;
    }else{
        String [] token3b = line2.split("[,|\\r?\\n]");
        int token2bi=Integer.parseInt(token3b[0]);
        double token2by=Double.parseDouble(token3b[2]);
        double token2bx=Double.parseDouble(token3b[1]);
        if (token2bx<(xmax-xmin)/(ymax-ymin)*token2by+xmin){
            ohnode.add(token2bi);
        }
        if (token2bx>(xmaxb-xminb)/(ymaxb-yminb)*token2by+xminb){
            ohnode.add(token2bi);
        }

     line2=scan2.nextLine();
     }
    }
   }
 }     
}

System.out.println(nodeb.size());  
System.out.println(node.size());
System.out.println(ohnode.size());
 for (int u=0;u<ohnode.size();u++)
  file.write(ohnode.get(u)+"\r\n");


file.close();   

}}
```

This is the text file I'm trying to use the Arraylist ohnode in:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.List;


public class TrimBox {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, StringIndexOutOfBoundsException, NumberFormatException{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("VspAircraft_calculix_geom.dat"));
    Scanner scan2 = new Scanner(new File("trimgroup.dat"));  
    FileWriter file = new FileWriter(new File("trimbox_nodes.dat"));

    ArrayList<Integer> node = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
//ALL the nodes of the entire wing

    while (scan.hasNextLine()){
        String line = scan.nextLine();
        String [] token= line.split(",|\\r?\\n]");

        if (token.length==2){
            for(int i=0;i<token[1].length()-11;i++) {
                if (token[1].substring(i,i+12).equals(" NSET=Nspar0")){
                    //Ask user to change the number after Nspar in modelcenter to denote which spar to apply load

                    line=scan.nextLine();
                    while(scan.hasNextLine()){
                        String [] token2= line.split("[,|\\r?\\n]");
                        if (token2[0].equals("")){
                            break;
                        }else{
                            String [] token3= line.split("[,|\\r?\\n]");
                            //System.out.println(token3[2]);
                            int token0d=Integer.parseInt(token3[0]);
                            node.add(token0d); //Add the node tokens to array node

                            //Order of the tokens from VSPAircraft_calculix_geom.data
                            //node, x value, y value, z value
                 }
             }
         }
     }
 }

}
}
}
/** We want to import the arraylist from trimgroup.dat (nodeb or ohnode?)
 * Can we also import arraylist node from trimgroup.dat?
 * -If nodes from VSP==nodeb (/ohnode?), skip, if not, add token to new array
 * -Write it to a new file
 * 
 * Probably can use some function of java.util.ArrayList to see if ArrayLists are equal
 * 
 * Why do we have ArrayLists instead of Arrays?  
 */
```

Comment: What do you mean by "import" in this context?

Comment: By File to File do you mean like from class-to-class or text document-to-text document?

Comment: I'm guessing that you've got the ArrayList in one object and want another object to be able to use it. If so, simply pass it into the second object via a constructor parameter or a "setter" method parameter -- easy as pie. But please don't make us guess. Please clarify your question so that we can all be talking about the same thing.

Comment: The question is not clear. Maybe if you show some code that would help understand what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Legend, I mean text document-to-text document.
I just want to be able to use an arraylist I've already created in another text document.

Comment: Sorry guys, I inherited this project from someone else in my research group, I'm completely new to Java, I'm trying to learn the syntax

Comment: You've got two classes that are essentially nothing more than two static main methods. If you want classes to interact, you have to move beyond this and create classes that produce functioning objects. I suggest that you continue on with your studies to learn how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell from your question what you are trying to do, so I shall make some guesses.

If you want to pass an ArrayList from one object to another, there are several ways to do this, but it depends which object you want to be 'in charge' of the transfer.

---

**1)** Object A could create an object B, and pass the ArrayList in the constructor:

```
new A(myArrayList);
```

---

**2)** if both objects already exist, object A could call a setter method in object B:

```
B.setList(myArrayList);
```

This assumes that A has a reference to B, and you have created a setter method in B! Setting objects like this is not necessarily good design, but that's another question.

---

**3)** object B could get the object from A with a getter method (or access it directly, depending on whether it is visible, e.g. `public` or `private`):

```
ArrayList myList = A.getList();

ArrayList myList = A.myArrayList;
```

Again, this assumes that B has a reference to A, and, in the first case, that you have created a getter method in A!

---

Finally note that [import](http://www.janeg.ca/scjp/lang/import.html) has a specific meaning in Java - see the imports at the top of the code you just posted, e.g:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
```

Importing the ArrayList class is not the same as passing actual ArrayList instances from one object or class to another.

---

**Update**: now that you've posted your code - see comments from *Hovercraft Full Of Eels*. You basically have two separate scripts, which are not designed to run together at the same time in the same JVM. They therefore can't pass an ArrayList between themselves, unless they write it to a shared file, or pass it over the network, which is a whole other question.